# how to read response of simple http request made in node

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

I am using the `request` module in node to make an http request. How do I read the response content of that request so that I can make a programmatic decision based on the response?

```
gulp.task("run-server-tests", function(){

    var responseJson = request("http://myurl/run-server-tests")

    plugins.util.log(responseJson); // not sure how to get at the response json

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

request allows you to use callback function, see [more detail](https://github.com/request/request)

```
request('http://www.google.com', function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    console.log(body) // Show the HTML for the Google homepage.
  }
})
```